# How to create a jQuery function to toggle dark mode?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm designing a dark mode for my website. Given I have a lot of written content, that would be especially helpful for evening reading. I have a toggle and have borrowed a function that seems to work so far:

```
$(function() {
  $(".switch").click(function() {
    $("#canvas-wrapper").css("background", "#222");
    $("p").css("color", "#DDD");
    });
});
```

I want the user to toggle these changes on and off as desired. However, when I attempt to add another line - defining a css change for another element - the function only applies the style to the first `#canvas-wrapper` element. Everything thereafter is ignored.

Is my syntax incorrect later in the function? Also, I need to write the function in a way that returns the CSS to its original state, should the user deactivate the toggle. How would I approach this?

I'm quite poor with jQuery and haven't had a ton of experience with the language.

Comment: In general, you'd do this by adding/removing a class to the `body` element, not individual things like `p` tags. You'd then have a bunch of CSS in your stylesheet to adjust all the individual tags/classes/IDs. A CSS pre-processor like Sass can really help with this.

Comment: Makes sense! I was trying that before but went with toggleClass. Seems to work a charm :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of changing every single element, you can define the dark mode styles in your CSS, and just use jQuery to toggle the dark-mode class.

I'm assuming clicking the .switch twice would change it back to light mode, and that your current CSS shows the light mode styles by default.

**CSS:**

```
#canvas-wrapper.dark-mode {
  background: #222;
  color: #DDD;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(function() {
  $(".switch").click(function() {
    $("#canvas-wrapper").toggleClass("dark-mode");
  });
});
```

If you like, you can use CSS variables as well. However, it would still involve class toggling/changing somewhere in your code. Using CSS variables but using vanilla JS: https://dev.to/ananyaneogi/create-a-dark-light-mode-switch-with-css-variables-34l8

Comment: Thank you! That is working perfectly, just a matter of setting things up now!

Comment: Everything is working well! Do you know how to add a store state to this? When someone travels to another page, the toggle resets and returns the website to its alternate appearance - definitely not intended. Thanks!

Comment: Understandable! You can check out localStorage or sessionStorage and on page load, check for the LS/SS variable you've created. If the variable exists, then you can addClass('dark-mode'). https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API

Answer (score 1):

you may have to write some css for each element whether its in light or dark mode. use javascript to toggle between the two. You can have a class for light mode (.light-mode) then one for dark mode. as long as class-wrapper is a div you should be ok.

I would use a js variable with global access for the mode and tie that into a function.

css

```
.light-mode{


    some more css classes for light mode

}

.dark-mode{


    some more css classes for dark mode

}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's great advice and gave me a good starting point for my CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use css with a target class. Jquery `toggleClass()` will do the job

```css
.bgDark{background: #4a4a4a !important;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div id="myDiv" class="" style="background: #fff393; border: 1px solid black;  width: 100px; height: 100px"></div>

<button onclick="$('#myDiv').toggleClass('bgDark')">toggle bg</button>
```

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate your input, but I marked another answer. Everyone provided such similar information.

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue by doing some tricks, direct answer for your question is by implement toggleClass for dark/light theme.

for example you look to this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/happyjoker/8hnxjvrk/)

```
<div class="change-color">
  <p>Hello World</p>
</div>

<div class="change-color">
  <p>Hello World 2</p>
</div>

<button>Change color</button>
```

and our script:

```
// find elements
var anotherColor = $(".change-color")
var button = $("button")

// handle click and add class
button.on("click", function(){
  anotherColor.toggleClass("another-color")
})
```

and our style:

```
body {
  background: #000;
  color: red;
}

button {
  background: #0084ff;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 8px 14px;
  font-size: 15px;
  color: #fff;
}

.another-color {
  background: #ddd;
}
```

But you can resolve issue too by using root variable color, for example:

```
:root {
  --color-bg: #000;
}

.default-color {
  background-color: var(--color-bg);
}

.another-color {
  --color-bg: #ddd;
}
```

You can look to this [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/happyjoker/8hnxjvrk/7/) too

Comment: Thank you! Your answer had a ton of detail. Much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The key ingredient is that you need **JQuery Cookie** **to remember your choice** wherever you are on the site. This way: *it will just reset to its default state*.